# Why is it giving me the error CS1525 ?? Something is bad?

Tags: c#, if-statement

PLEASE HELP !!
I don't know what is going on, this piece of my stupid code does not work.
Please help me because I am a newbie to c# and I am just trying to do some code to practice.
I wrote an "If statement" and normally it should work with: {}, but it doesn't.
And there are other several problems, here is the output above the code :

```
main.cs(14,30): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `{'
main.cs(17,6): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `else'
main.cs(23,246): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `end-of-file'
Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 0 warnings
compiler exit status 1
```

// this is the code

```
using System;


public class LOOOOOL {
public static void Main(String [] args)
{
  int enterInfo;
  int question1;
{
  Console.WriteLine("LOOOOOL");
  enterInfo = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine(enterInfo);
  question1 = Console.WriteLine("Is that what you wrote ???");







      if(String.Contains("y") {
    Console.WriteLine("So that's cool, right ???");
  }
      else
  {







    Console.WriteLine("Can you re-write it please ???");
     question1 = Console.ReadLine();
     Console.WriteLine(question1);
  }

}
```

Comment: you're missing a closing )

Comment: Consistent indentation makes these issues *much* easier to spot.

Comment: Screaming PLEASE HELP will almost always get you a couple extra downvotes.  *Everyone* posting here needs help - we know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing a closing parathesis:

```
if(String.Contains("y")) //<---missing extra )
```

you have an extra bracket:

```
 int question1;
 { //<----what's that doing there?
 Console.WriteLine("LOOOOOL");
```

Reformatted code should look as such:

```
using System;

public class LOOOOOL 
{
    public static void Main(String [] args)
    {
        int enterInfo;
        int question1;

        Console.WriteLine("LOOOOOL");
        enterInfo = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(enterInfo);
        question1 = Console.WriteLine("Is that what you wrote ???");

        if(String.Contains("y"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("So that's cool, right ???");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Can you re-write it please ???");
            question1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(question1);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your variables are `int`... it will **never** contain "y".... might want to change those two to strings

Also... `String.Contains()`... what string are you checking? Something for you to look into :)

Perhaps, `enterInfo.Contains("y")` might be userful for you.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I am so stupid !!! But please why is it telling me main.cs(23,246): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `end-of-file'

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: here i'll post how your code should look as my answer give me a second

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH GUYS YOU'RE GREAT